# According to Cartesian substance dualism, would it be possible for an individual's mind to be replaced by another mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body

Say an individual's Cartesian mind has been removed from that person (somehow). Would it be possible (in principle) for another mind to take over the "mindless hulk" of an individual?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This is a common assumption among spiritual dualists.  Stephen Braude discusses it here:

https://www.survivalafterdeath.info/articles/braude/drop-in.htm

Ian Stevenson, in his child past life field studies, encountered several adult drop ins: https://med.virginia.edu/perceptual-studies/wp-content/uploads/sites/267/2015/11/STE29Stevenson-1.pdf https://www.questia.com/library/journal/1G1-17935536/possession-and-exorcism-an-essay-review

And JP Moreland considers all of Stevenson's data is drop ins:  https://clearlens.org/thought-snack-evidence-for-reincarnation-or-possession/

Comment: But if someones mind is swapped, would that mean that they would behave different and remember different experiences? Or, since the mind is dependent on the brain, the person with the swapped mind would behave the same and not share the different experiences?

Comment: Excorcism or depossession is based on a dualist assumption that memories, personality, and skills come with the possessing entitity, and are not solely generated by a brain.  Here is a sample discussion:  http://sshc.in/?p=1172